# Мульти загрузка PHP

Tags: php, html, javascript

Есть мульти-загрузчик картинок

```
<input type="file" name="userfile[]" multiple="multiple" title="Загрузите одну или несколько фотографий">
```

В PHP (upload.php) написано так:

```
        if($_POST['send'])
    {
        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['userfile']['name']); $i++) 
        {
            $imageinfo = @getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i]);
            $uploaddir = '../lib/uploads/';
            $original_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
            $ext = pathinfo($original_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // расширение
            $file_name = md5(basename($original_name).time()).'.'.$ext; // новое имя файла
            $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file_name; // полный путь
             if($imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/gif' && $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/jpeg' && $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/png' && $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/jpg') 
             {
                echo "Извините, к загрузке принимаются только картинки JPG,GIF,PNG.<br /><a href='/admin/upload.php?method=2'>Назад</a>";
                exit;
             }
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploadfile)) 
            {
                echo "Картнинка успешно загружена.";
                $smarty->assign("filename","http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/lib/uploads/".$file_name.$_POST['url']);
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Неизвестная ошибка.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Работаю со smarty, и строка 
`$smarty->assign("filename","http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/lib/uploads/".$file_name.$_POST['url']);` изменяет значение hidden-формы на ссылку с картинкой. Но вот проблема: в нее записывается только последняя картинка. А мне нужно так: я допустим выбрал 5 картинок, загрузил их и hidden-форма получила значение картинок в таком формате:
http://test.com/image2|http://test.com/image3 и т.д., т.е записать туда все ссылки загруженных картинок.

Comment: А почему бы сначала не собирать строку по мере загрузки и только потом отправлять дальше на обработку?

Comment: Как ее собрать? Форма кидает запрос по-несколько раз, к примеру: есть 5 картинок, к файлу upload.php придет 5 запросов. Собсно, где хранить предыдущие картинки?

Comment: Я понятия не имею о работе Smarty и уж тем более, не знаю, что описывает метод **assign**, но могу предположить, что можно было бы делать что-то в этом роде:

    $image_array = array();
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploadfile)){
     echo "Картнинка успешно загружена.";
     $image_array["filename".$i] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/lib/uploads/".$file_name.$_POST['url'];
    }
    if(count($image_array) > 0){
     $smarty->assign($image_array);
    }

Comment: Или если не массив, а строка в том виде, как вы показали, то:

    $image_string = array();
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploadfile)){
     echo "Картнинка успешно загружена.";
     $image_array[] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/lib/uploads/".$file_name.$_POST['url'];
    }
    if(count($image_array) > 0){
     $smarty->assign("filename",implode('|',$image_array));
    }

Comment: Что в цикле? Компоновать массив? Да. А отправлять данные  - уже после цикла.

Comment: @Deonis спасибо, помогло.

Comment: Делайте append массива